# Update a column only if value of two columns(combination of both) are present else insert all values in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, insert-update

In my Oracle DB, There are 3 columns in table `'basic_comment'` & columns are (`product_id`,`comment`,`comment_id`).

I have to update a column 'comment' only if combination of columns(product_id and comment_id) is already present else insert in all the three columns.  For ex:

```
product_id     comment     comment_id  
Ac2108         fixed          5  
Ac7108         configure      3  
As2108         fixed          5
```

so here if (Ac2108 and 5) is present then for same row I need to change comment from `'fixed'` to `'configure'` or if not then insert into all the columns. Columns are to be inserted from another table `"static_comment"`.
I have tried a merge query but it is updating other rows too in "basic_comment" table.

```
MERGE 
INTO  basic_comment a 
USING static_comment b
ON  ( a.product_id = b.product_id and a.comment_id = b.comment_id )    
WHEN MATCHED 
THEN 
 UPDATE
SET a.comment = b.comment
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN 
INSERT ( a.product_id
, a.comment
, a.comment_id
VALUES ( b.product_id
, b.comment
, b.comment_id);
```

Comment: I don't see mistakes in your query. Your query must only update the rows for which condition `( a.product_id = b.product_id and a.comment_id = b.comment_id )` is true.
How many rows does table `static_comment` contain?

Comment: Works for me... no other rows were updated. Are you absolutely certain that you provided query that you are really using? For instance, column name in Oracle cannot be 'comment', and you did not close bracket in INSERT statement (after a.comment_id). Please remove reference to mysql as this is Oracle question.

Comment: If this is Oracle, why do I see MySQL tag??????  Please tag properly.

Answer (score 0):

If having trouble with the merge, could do two seperate statements, obviously not as quick, but if dataset is small it will do

```
Update table
Set comment = ‘configure’
Where product_id is not null and comment_id is not null

Insert into table2(....,....)
Select comment_id, ‘static’
From table
Where not ( product_id is not null and comment_id is not null)
```